# JavaCC - Match some words except some others

Tags: java, regex, parsing, javacc

I am trying to create a parser for first-order logic using the javacc and I have the following problem.

I have this: 
< VARIABLE : < LOWER > (< INNER >)* > 
where 
< #INNER : 
    ( 
      < UPPER >
    | < LOWER >
    | < DIGIT >
    | < UNDERSCORE >
    ) >
< #DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ] >
< #LOWER : [ "a"-"z" ] >
< #UPPER : [ "A"-"Z" ] >
< #UNDERSCORE: "_" >

, but I want to exclude some words from this. In particular i want to exclude the words sum, count, avg, max and min. Is there a way to to this? In other words, I want the variables to begin with a lowercase letter followed by any number of inner tokens, where the inner token may be an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, a digit or an underscore. However, i do not want the variables to take values such as sum, count, avg, max and min.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaCC picks the first regular expression that matches the longest string, all you need to do is put the rules for your reserved words first.  For example

```
TOKEN : {
    <SUM : "sum">
|   <COUNT: "count">
|   <AVG: "avg" >
|   <MIN: "min">
|   <MAX: "max" >
/* The next rule must come after the ones above. */
|   < VARIABLE : < LOWER > (< INNER >)* > 
}
```

The placement of the fragment rules (#INNER, #LOWER, etc) does not matter.